# Openwrt: build error

Tags: linux, svn, openwrt, buildroot

I'am building openWrt for an Arduino Yun board, i'am following the steps descibed in [this link](https://github.com/arduino/openwrt-yun), however i'am getting a build erreur: 
`svn: E160013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://opkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk'`, by accessing this page using the internet browser the page is really not found. Could anyone help me resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Google Code hosting service is now defunct. Therefore, the version-control repository http://opkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk is not available anymore.

Read the [project's page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/opkg/) carefully to learn how to obtain the source of the project.